# Uniform distribution problem(Problem 6.13 First course in probability)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A man and a woman agree to meet at a certain location about 12:30
> P.M. If the man arrives at a time uniformly distributed between 12:15
> and 12:45, and if the woman independently arrives at a time uniformly
> distributed between 12:00 and 1 P.M., find the probability that the
> first to arrive waits no longer than 5 minutes.

Let us call $X$ ~ $U(15, 45)$ is the minute offset from 12:00 from the time the man arrives and $Y$ ~ $U(0, 60)$ is the minute offset from 12:00 from the time the woman arrives. Then what we have to calculate is:

$$P(X-5\leq Y \leq X  \lor Y - 5 \leq X \leq Y) = P(X-5\leq Y \leq X) + P(Y - 5 \leq X \leq Y)$$, since $P(Y - 5 \leq X \leq Y, X-5\leq Y \leq X) = 0$

$$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) =  \frac{1}{30} \frac{1}{60}= \frac{1}{1800}$$ So:

Firstly:

$$P(X-5\leq Y \leq X) = \int_{15}^{45} \int_{x-5}^{x} \frac{1}{1800} \,dy \,dx = \frac{5(30)}{1800} = \frac{1}{12}$$

Secondly:

$$P(Y - 5 \leq X \leq Y) = \left(\int_{15}^{20} \int_{15}^{y} + \int_{20}^{45} \int_{y-5}^{y} + \int_{45}^{50}\int_{45}^{45} \right)\left(\frac{1}{1800} \,dx \,dy \right) = \frac{11}{144}$$

This is because $x$ can't run from $y-5$ to $y$ directly ($X$~$U(15, 45)$)

So the result is $\frac{11}{144} + \frac{1}{12} =  \frac{23}{144}$. But the right answer is  $\frac{1}{6}$, which is confusing. I'm not sure where I am wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The last integral limit you should have from $y - 5$ to $45$.

$$ \int_{15}^{20} \int_{15}^{y} \frac {1} {1800} dx dy 
= \int_{15}^{20} \frac {y - 15} {1800} dy 
= \left. \frac {y(y - 30)} {3600} \right|_{15}^{20}
= \frac {-200 + 225} {3600}
= \frac {25} {3600} 
= \frac {1} {144} $$

$$ \int_{20}^{45} \int_{y-5}^{y} \frac {1} {1800} dx dy 
= \int_{20}^{45} \frac {5} {1800} dy 
= (45 - 20) \times \frac {1} {360} 
= \frac {25} {360}
= \frac {10} {144} $$

In you calculation you treated the last integral as $0$ so you have
$$ \frac {1} {144} + \frac {10} {144} = \frac {11} {144} $$

In fact the last integral is similar to the first one by symmetry
$$ \int_{45}^{50} \int_{y-5}^{45} \frac {1} {1800} dx dy 
= \int_{45}^{50} \frac {50 - y} {1800} dy 
= \left. \frac {y(100 - y)} {3600} \right|_{45}^{50}
= \frac {2500 - (50^2 - 5^2)} {3600}
= \frac {25} {3600} 
= \frac {1} {144} $$

So we have the additional $1/144$ and thus the resulting probability for $X \in (Y - 5, Y)$ is

$$ \frac {1} {144} + \frac {10} {144} + \frac {1} {144} = \frac {12} {144} = \frac {1} {12} $$

which gives the ultimate result to be $1/6$

Actually in your calculation conditional on $X$ will be easier:
$$ \Pr\{Y - 5 \leq X \leq Y\} = \Pr\{X \leq Y \leq X + 5\}
= \int_{15}^{45} \Pr\{x \leq Y \leq x + 5\} \frac {1} {30} dx
= \int_{15}^{45} \frac {5} {60} \frac {1} {30} dx
= \frac {1} {12} \frac {1} {30} \times 30 dx
= \frac {1} {12} $$

Or, if you are allowed to use the graphical method without giving the detailed calculation step, you can plot the joint pdf on the $(x, y)$-plane, which gives you a rectangle (depicted in red below). And the region of $|x - y| \leq 5$ are the region depicted in green below, bounded by the two lines $y = x + 5$ and $y = x - 5$. It is easy to see that the intersecting region is a parallelogram with base $5 + 5 = 10$ and height $45 - 15 = 30$. So the required probability = $10 \times 30 / 1800 = 10/60 = 1/6$

The interpretation of the graphic is that given each realized value of $X$, $Y$ need to be in the window of $(X - 5, X + 5)$ which has an exact length of $10$ regardless of the actual realization. So the probability is $10 / 60$ = $1/6$.

[image]

Comment: In short: $$\mathsf P(Y - 5 \leq X \leq Y) = \left(\int_{15}^{20} \int_{15}^{y} + \int_{20}^{45} \int_{y-5}^{y} + \int_{45}^{50}\int_{\color{red}{y-5}}^{45} \right)\left(\frac{1}{1800} \,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy \right) = \frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: And of course$$\mathsf P(\lvert X-Y\rvert\leq 5) = \int_{15}^{45}\int_{x-5}^{x+5}\dfrac{1}{1800}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm d x = \dfrac 16$$